# How do I create an incremental index with jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a json like that :

```
[
    {"data":"a"},
    {"data":"b"},
    {"data":"c"}
]
```

using jq I want to add an incremental id field like that:

```
[
    {"data":"a","id":"xx_1"},
    {"data":"b","id":"xx_2"},
    {"data":"c","id":"xx_3"}
]
```

I can't seem to get the right jq command for that, anyone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
to_entries | map( (.value.id = "xx_\(1+.key)" ) | .value)
```

Here's another method, which however requires jq 1.5:

```
def add_id(prefix):
  [ foreach .[] as $o (0;
      . + 1;
      $o + {"id": (prefix + tostring) }) ];

add_id("xx_")
```

Example:

```
$ jq -c -f add_id.jq
[ {"data":"a"}, {"data":"b"}, {"data":"c"} ]
```

Output:

```
[{"data":"a","id":"xx_1"},{"data":"b","id":"xx_2"},{"data":"c","id":"xx_3"}]
```

A third approach would be to use `transpose`:

```
def add_id(prefix):
  [ .,  [ range(0;length) | {"id": (prefix + tostring) } ] ]
  | transpose | map(add);
```

(If your jq does not have transpose/0, it's jq definition can readily be found, e.g. by googling.)

Answer (score 5):

Here are two solutions.  One using **foreach** which holds a counter in the foreach state while iterating over the input array collecting values back into a result array.  This is similar to [peak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997358/peak)'s **add_id** function.

```
[
  foreach .[] as $e (
     0
   ; .+1
   ; $e + {"id":"xx_\(.)"}
  )
]
```

and one using **reduce** which holds the input array in the reduce state while iterating over the array indices, updating each element.

```
reduce range(0,length) as $i (
     .
   ; .[$i].id = "xx_\($i+1)"
)
```

I think the **reduce** is the simpler one for this case.

Answer (score 1):

`enumerate/1` as defined below is a useful, generic library function that can be used for problems such as this. It's stream-oriented, which also makes it worthwhile knowing about.

To be consistent with jq's "index origin", it starts counting from 0, and hence the `first + 1` to satisfy the requirements of this particular problem:

```
  def enumerate(s): foreach s as $x (-1; .+1; [., $x]);
  [enumerate(.[]) | last + {id: "xx_\(first + 1)"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var data=[
    {"data":"a"},
    {"data":"b"},
    {"data":"c"}
    ];
    var cnt=0;
    data.map(function(data){
       data.id="xx_"+cnt;
       cnt++;
    })

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Sorry,I forgot to mention that I need to create it using bash... I'll edit