# How can I replace every matching JSON field's value with incremental value?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep, jq

So I have a large json file (approximately 20k hosts) and for each host, I need to find FieldA and replace it's value with a unique value which I can then swap back later.

For instance:

`root> cat file.json | jq .`

```
[
   {
   "id": 1,
   "uptime": 0
   "computer_name": "Computer01"
   },
   {
   "id": 2,
   "uptime": 0
   "computer_name": "Computer02"
   }
]
```

I need to iterate through this list of 20k hosts, replace every computer_name with a dummy value:

```
[
   {
   "id": 1,
   "uptime": 0
   "computer_name": "Dummy01"
   },
   {
   "id": 2,
   "uptime": 0
   "computer_name": "Dummy02"
   }
]
```

And if possible, export the dummy value and original value to a table side by side linking them up.

The dummy values I want to generate automatically such as:
for each computer_name replace value with Dummy?????? where ????? is a number from 00000 to 99999 and it just iterates through this.

I attempted to use: `cat file.json | jq .computer_name` OR `jq.computer_name file.json` to filter this down and then work on replacing the values, but when I use .computer_name as the value, I get this error:

jq: error : Cannot index array with string "computer_name".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might help: [How do I create an incremental index with jq](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34510742/3776858)

Comment: I now have: `for i in $(jq '.[] | .computer_name' file.json); do echo $i; done` which gives me the hostnames. Now I just need to replace with the dummy value and also add to table.

Comment: Your JSON in your question is not valid (missing two `,`). Please fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I would first generate a master table containing both the clear and the obfuscated names,
then extract from it as needed either the protected version by removing the clear names,
or a table with the matchings. You can even perform direct lookups on it:

```bash
jq 'with_entries(.key |= "Dummy\("\(.)" | "0"*(5-length) + .)" | .value += {
  clear_name: .value.computer_name,
  computer_name: .key
})' file.json > master.json
```

```bash
cat master.json
{
  "Dummy00000": {
    "id": 1,
    "uptime": 0,
    "computer_name": "Dummy00000",
    "clear_name": "Computer01"
  },
  "Dummy00001": {
    "id": 2,
    "uptime": 0,
    "computer_name": "Dummy00001",
    "clear_name": "Computer02"
  }
}
```

```bash
jq 'map(del(.clear_name))' master.json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "uptime": 0,
    "computer_name": "Dummy00000"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "uptime": 0,
    "computer_name": "Dummy00001"
  }
]
```

```bash
jq -r '.[] | [.clear_name, .computer_name] | @tsv' master.json
Computer01  Dummy00000
Computer02  Dummy00001
```

```bash
jq --arg lookup "Dummy00001" '.[$lookup]' master.json
{
  "id": 2,
  "uptime": 0,
  "computer_name": "Dummy00001",
  "clear_name": "Computer02"
}
```

```bash
jq -r --arg lookup "Dummy00001" '.[$lookup].clear_name' master.json
Computer02
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean exactly by "exporting the dummy value and original value", but the following should be sufficient for you to figure out that detail, since the result contains the information necessary to create the table:

```
  def lpad($len; $fill): tostring | ($len - length) as $l | ($fill * $l)[:$l] + .;

  . as $in
  | ([length|tostring|length, 5]|max) as $width
  | [range(0; length) as $i
     | $in[$i] 
     | . + {computer_name: ("Dummy" + ($i | lpad($width;"0"))), 
            original_name: .computer_name}]
```

You could use this to create your table, and then remove `original_name`
e.g., by running:

```
map(del(.original_name))
```

Of course there are other ways to achieve your stated goal, but if leaving the original names in the file is an option, then that might be worth considering, since it might obviate the need to maintain a separate table.